# Making Multiline graphs with Groupby sub sets

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I am using Pandas and Matplotlib in to make visualizations. I am having trouble creating a graph even though I feel as though I have all the information I should need.

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
%matplotlib inline
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 5, 4
sb.set_style('ticks')
B = df.groupby(['DATE']).BOROUGH.value_counts()
B

DATE        BOROUGH      
2018-02-14  QUEENS           205
            BROOKLYN         160
            MANHATTAN        123
            BRONX             85
            STATEN ISLAND     30
2018-02-15  QUEENS           177
            BROOKLYN         160
            MANHATTAN        130
            BRONX             84
            STATEN ISLAND     24
2018-02-16  QUEENS           152
            BROOKLYN         125
            MANHATTAN        118
            BRONX             90
            STATEN ISLAND     24
2018-02-17  QUEENS           163
            MANHATTAN        138
            BROOKLYN         130
            BRONX             76
            STATEN ISLAND     16
2018-02-18  QUEENS           138
            BROOKLYN         104
            MANHATTAN         96
            BRONX             54
            STATEN ISLAND     22
2018-02-19  QUEENS           132
            BROOKLYN         127
            MANHATTAN         60
            BRONX             53
            STATEN ISLAND     11
2018-02-20  QUEENS           141
            BROOKLYN         134
            MANHATTAN         73
            BRONX             57
            STATEN ISLAND      8
```

How can I plot this subset where x is the date and each Borough forms a seperate line on the same graph?

Comment: Help me make my question better, rather than down voting and not showing me what to improve.

Comment: @downvoters, would you mind to explain what is wrong with the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unstack your series and plot it as a regular DF:

```
B.unstack().plot()
```

[image]

Result of "unstacking":

```
In [41]: B.unstack()
Out[41]:
BOROUGH     BRONX  BROOKLYN  MANHATTAN  QUEENS  STATEN ISLAND
DATE
2018-02-14     85       160        123     205             30
2018-02-15     84       160        130     177             24
2018-02-16     90       125        118     152             24
2018-02-17     76       130        138     163             16
2018-02-18     54       104         96     138             22
2018-02-19     53       127         60     132             11
2018-02-20     57       134         73     141              8
```

Comment: Perfekt! Du hast mir sehr geholfen

Comment: @VVAPRLBRE, glad i could help :)